# Index change event C#

Tags: c#, listbox, selectedindexchanged

I was just wondering if there was anyway to execute the index change event for the first iteration.

My code looks like the following.

```
    private void cboxEvent_IndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int value;

        value = cboxEvent.SelectedIndex;

        resetListBoxes(); 

        cboxEvent.SelectedIndex = value;

        csvExport(); 


    }

    private void cboxSLA_IndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;

        value = cboxSLA.SelectedIndex;

        resetListBoxes(); 

        cboxNPA.SelectedIndex = value;

        csvExport(); 
    }
    private void cboxNPA_IndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;

        value = cboxNPA.SelectedIndex;

        resetListBoxes(); 

        cboxNPA.SelectedIndex = value;

        csvExport(); 

    }
```

The problem is that once an index changes it resets the other listboxes and their Index change method is activated as well. Therefore it executes Their IndexChange method.

I would like for the code to be executed only once for the first Index Changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Chris

Comment: It looks like you've missed to include code for `resetListBoxes` in your question. It makes your logic a bit unclear. What's happening in that method, and why you're calling it from each `IndexChange` method?

Comment: The reason I am calling it from the index change method is because I want the code to activate every-time the user changes the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your IndexChanged handlers in this manner (same for all handlers):

```
private bool _IgnoreIndexChange;

private void cboxEvent_IndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_IgnoreIndexChange)
        return;

    _IgnoreIndexChange = true;
    try
    {
        int value;
        value = cboxEvent.SelectedIndex;
        resetListBoxes(); 
        cboxEvent.SelectedIndex = value;
        csvExport(); 
    }
    finally
    {
        _IgnoreIndexChange = false;
    }    
}
```

So if any index will be changed by user - only IndexChanged handler of that combobox will run, no others.

Comment: Wow your a genius! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

keep a boolean variable to check wether the IndexChanged Event fired from user or from another event handler and proceed further only if the IndexChanged event fired from the user.

Comment: How would I know if it was activated from user or from event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.Focused** property to manipulate
The idea is to set the focus off to disable the second iteration.

You would need a Label as a *Focus Switcher*

Declare one as a global variable;

```
Label x;
```

It would be like this

```
private void cboxEvent_IndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cboxEvent.Focused)
    {
        int value;
        value = cboxEvent.SelectedIndex;
        resetListBoxes(); 
        csvExport(); 
        x.Focus();
    }
    if(!cboxEvent.Focused)
        cboxEvent.SelectedIndex = value;
}
```

And goes the same to another 2 Combo Boxes..

Comment: I tried it. It still goes into a loop. The loop occurs because Once one index it changes, it alters the other indexes and the methods keep on executing infinitely. Thats why I only want to have it execute once.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the misunderstanding earlier. I've wrote a several reworked solution. Hope it could help!

Comment: Thank you very much Michael! Really appreciate it!